# Should I report bugs/issues with applications on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I sometimes encounter a buggy/unexpected behavior in applications which have an issue tracker.

Should I then raise a question on Stack Overflow, or is it irrelevant to the site?

There was a comment on my [latest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49489721) question that it's not the proper place to ask such questions.

I didn't find an answer on the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company

Comment: @Robert Longson link look more about general questions, but my question is very programmatic (and specific),

Comment: If you did not program this app then your question doesn't belong at SO.  Simply because any advice you'd get would be useless to you.

Comment: @Hans Passant sometimes I'm using the application wrong or using wrong plugin for example and also known issues can be introduce/explained

Comment: In this particular case, the OP didn't know that it is a bug, and the advice ("it is a bug") is (somewhat) useful.

Comment: Knowing I can write off my New York taxes on my Connecticut taxes is useful too... Just because something is useful doesn't mean it belongs on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you encounter buggy behavior in an app/library I would recommend going to that app's site or github if its a library and search for known bugs.
If you don't find it there, don't ask on SO if it is a bug, but ask how to solve it.